# Access paper dimensions

Tags: paper-size, dimensions

How can I access the paper dimension that are in use when compiling a document? In other words, I am looking for a command that returns the width and height of the paper used (so that the returned parameters would change if the paper size is changed).

Comment: You should just use the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to set these dimensions. I guess it's not entire clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth`

Comment: @Werner: I want to access the paper dimensions so that I can use the ratio between them when setting new margins with the geometry package. I want to set margins based on the rule to keep the text-block width-to-height ratio equal to that in the paper (while also setting the left and right margins equal, and the bottom margin to half of the top margin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\the\paperheight

\the\paperwidth

\the\textheight

\the\textwidth

\paperheight=111pt
\the\paperheight

\end{document}
```

[image]

changing the paper height in the documents body doesn't change the text height

Comment: Where does `\paperheight`/`\paperwidth` come from?

Comment: defined in `latex.ltx` and set by the documentclass